# Suppose $f$ is continous and is injective in $[a,b]$ and $g$ has primitive then $f.g$ has primitive.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is continous in $[a,b]$ and is injective in $[a,b]$. Moreover  $g$ has primitive prove that $f.g$ has primitive.

**My attempt:**

$g$ has primitive implies that exists a differentiable function $G$ such that $g(x)=G'(x)$ for all $x\in[a,b]$

Let $\epsilon>0$
Moreover, as $f$ is continuous in $[a,b]$ exists $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-x_0|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$

As $f$ is injective then for all $x,y\in[a,b]$ such that $x\not =y$ then $f(x)\not = f(y)$

We need show that exists a differentiable function $F.G$ such that $f(x)g(x)=F'(x)G(x)+F(x)G'(x)$ for all $x\in[a,b]$

Here, i'm stuck. can someone help me?